# php form giving error

Tags: php, html, forms, captcha

I have this form and up until a few days ago it was working fine, now it displays "address required" regardless of entering in an address into the field.

Below is the code of the form I'm using.

```
isset($_POST['d1_add'])
```

This is the if(empty statement:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
 echo "         <ul>\n";
    if(empty($d1_fname))    {echo "         <li>First Name Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_lname))    {echo "         <li>Last Name Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_add))      {echo "         <li>Address Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_city))     {echo "         <li>City     Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if($d1_state=="STATE")  {echo "         <li>State Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_zip))      {echo "         <li>Zip Code Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_county))   {echo "         <li>County Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_email))    {echo "         <li>E-Mail Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_phone1) || empty($d1_phone2) ||empty($d1_phone3))
                        {echo "         <li>Phone Number Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_contact))  {echo "         <li>Preferred Contact Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
```

This is the form part:

```
<td>Street Address</td>
<td><input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_add" size="20" type="text" 
<?php if(!empty($d1_add)){echo 'value="'.$d1_add.'" ';} ?>/></td>
```

My URL also expired a few days ago, could this cause my captcha keys to fail? Or is there some other reason it would of messed up? I haven't touched this website in a long time, and nothing has been changed.

Is there any reason this could have broke aside from the form being invalid somehow?

Also if you need me to post all of the code I will, I just pulled the parts I assumed where necessary.

Also the url of the page that's messed up is:
https://www.mymra.com/Motorcycle_Insurance_Quote.php

All of my code:

```
<?php
    function setinclude(){
        $levels = substr_count($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/');
        $root = '';
        for($i = 1; $i < $levels; $i++){$root .= '../';}   
        set_include_path($root);
    }      
    setinclude();
    session_start(); 
    include 'site/config.php';
    require_once 'site/inc/smtpmail.php';
    $linkedURL = $secureURL;

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on') {
    header('Location: '.$secureURL.'/Motorcycle_Insurance_Quote.php');
}


    //require_once('site/inc/recaptchalib.php');
    //$recaptcha_publickey = '6Le2lt8SAAAAANUh2Qlb0ncvg7pGB79eP52ijeXV';
    //$recaptcha_privatekey = '6Le2lt8SAAAAAMSkGyo0HHV8hhcL7PWWm3fVN90d';


if (
isset($_POST['d1_fname'])           ||  isset($_POST['d1_lname'])   ||
isset($_POST['d1_mname'])           ||  isset($_POST['d1_sname'])   ||
isset($_POST['d1_add'])             ||
isset($_POST['d1_city'])            ||  isset($_POST['d1_state'])   ||  isset($_POST['d1_zip'])     ||
isset($_POST['d1_county'])          ||
isset($_POST['d1_phone1'])          ||  isset($_POST['d1_phone2'])  ||  isset($_POST['d1_phone3'])  ||
isset($_POST['d1_email'])           ||
isset($_POST['d1_contact'])
    ) {

        // Reverse magic_quotes_gpc/magic_quotes_sybase effects on those vars if ON.
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            if(ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase')) {
                $d1_fname           = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_fname']);
                $d1_lname           = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_lname']);
                $d1_mname           = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_mname']);
                $d1_sname           = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_sname']);
                $d1_add             = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_add']);
                $d1_city            = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_city']);
                $d1_state           = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_state']);
                $d1_zip             = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_zip']);
                $d1_county          = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_county']);
                $d1_phone1          = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_phone1']);
                $d1_phone2          = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_phone2']);
                $d1_phone3          = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_phone3']);
                $d1_email           = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_email']);
                $d1_contact         = str_replace("''", "'", $_POST['d1_contact']);
            } else {
                $d1_fname           = stripslashes($_POST['d1_fname']);
                $d1_lname           = stripslashes($_POST['d1_lname']);
                $d1_mname           = stripslashes($_POST['d1_mname']);
                $d1_sname           = stripslashes($_POST['d1_sname']);
                $d1_add             = stripslashes($_POST['d1_add']);
                $d1_city            = stripslashes($_POST['d1_city']);
                $d1_state           = stripslashes($_POST['d1_state']);
                $d1_zip             = stripslashes($_POST['d1_zip']);
                $d1_county          = stripslashes($_POST['d1_county']);
                $d1_phone1          = stripslashes($_POST['d1_phone1']);
                $d1_phone2          = stripslashes($_POST['d1_phone2']);
                $d1_phone3          = stripslashes($_POST['d1_phone3']);
                $d1_email           = stripslashes($_POST['d1_email']);   
                $d1_contact         = stripslashes($_POST['d1_contact']);
            }
        } else {
                $d1_fname           = $_POST['d1_fname'];
                $d1_lname           = $_POST['d1_lname'];
                $d1_mname           = $_POST['d1_mname'];
                $d1_sname           = $_POST['d1_sname'];
                $d1_city            = $_POST['d1_city'];
                $d1_state           = $_POST['d1_state'];
                $d1_zip             = $_POST['d1_zip'];
                $d1_county          = $_POST['d1_county'];
                $d1_phone1          = $_POST['d1_phone1'];
                $d1_phone2          = $_POST['d1_phone2'];
                $d1_phone3          = $_POST['d1_phone3'];
                $d1_email           = $_POST['d1_email'];
                $d1_contact         = $_POST['d1_contact'];
        }        
      }

include 'site/inc/www2-metas.php';
?>

<title>Free Motorcycle Insurance Quote - Affordable Motorcycle Insurance</title>
<meta name="description" content="Get your Free Motorcycle Insurance Quote from the Motorcycle Professionals at the MRA (Motorcycle Riders Association).  We will quote you with several different companies and get you the best rate.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Harley-Davidson, Harley Davidson, Motorcycle Motorclub, motorcycle insurance, motorcycle towing, biker, motorcycle, harley, davidson, sportbike,sportbikes,motorcycle club,motorcycle organization,motorcycle,organizations,motorcycle clubs,motorcycle association,motorcycle associations,motorcycle tour,motorcycle tours,motorcycle touring,motorcycle rider,motorcycle riders,motorcycle stuff,motorcycle event,motorcycle events,honda motorcycle,honda motorcycles,honda,bmw,bmw motorcycle,bmw motorcycles,bmw insurance,honda insurance,yamaha,yamaha motorcycle,yamaha motorcycles,yamahas,yamaha insurance,kawasaki,kawasaki motorcycle,kawasaki motorcycles,kawasaki insurance,kawasaki sportbikes,kawasaki sportbike,crotch rocket,crotch rockets,crotch rockets,rice burner,rice rocket,dirt bike,dirtbike,dirt bikes,dirtbikes,motocross,motorcross,daytona,daytona beach,bike week,bikeweek,daytona beach bikeweek,daytona beach bike week,daytona beach harley davidson,daytona beach harley-davidson,daytona beach harley,bike shop,bike shops,harley shop,harley shops,indian,indian motorcycle,indian motorcycles,boot hill,boothill,daytona boothill,daytona boot hill,daytona boot hill,boot hill saloon,froggy,froggy's,daytona froggy's,motorcycle racing,motorcycle races,motorcycle drag strip,motorcycle drags,ahdra,all harley drag racing association,aaa,triple a,roadside assistance,towing,big dog motorcycles,big dog,boss hoss,boss hoss motorcycles,suzuki,suzuki motorcyles,suzuki parts,suzuki shop,volusia,volusia motorcycle,volusia motorcycles,suzuki volusia,v-star,v star,yamaha v-star,road star,yamaha road star,v-star motorcycles,v-star motorcycle,v star motorcycle,v star motorcycles,gold wing,goldwing,honda goldwing,honda gold wing,gold wing motorcycles,gold wing motorcycle,Goldwing motorcycle,goldwing motorcycles,honda hoot,wing ding,honda wing ding,sturgis,sturgis south dakota,sturgis rally,sturgis rally and races,black hills rally,black hills south dakota,laconia,laconia races,myrtle beach bike week,myrtle beach bikeweek,myrtle beach,deal's gap,deals gap,motorcycle rally,motorcycle rallys,motorcycle show,bike show,flat track,flat track racing,arlen ness,ness,arlen ness motorcycles,jesse james,jesse james motorcycles,west coast,westcoast,westcoast choppers,west coast choppers,easy rider,ez rider,choppers,chopper,perowitz,dave perowitz,dave perowitz motorcycles,nhra drag racing,nhra motorcycle,harley pipes,harley parts,vance & hines,triumph,triumph,motorcycles,corbin,corbin seats,motorcycle safety foundation,trikes,progressive,progressive motorcycle insurance,aprilia,aprilia motorcycles,v-rod,v rod harley v rod,harley v-rod,harley davidson v rod,harley davidson v-rod,fatboy,fat boy,harley fatboy,harley fat boy,softtail,harley softtail,harley davidson softtail,heritage softtail,harley heritage softtail,harley davidson heritage softtail,vulcan,kawasaki vulcan,geico,geico direct,geico motorcycle insurance,dairyland,dairyland motorcycle insurance,road king,roadking,harley road king,harley roadking,harley davidson road king,harley davidson roadking,corbin motorcycle seats,sportster,sporty,harley sportster,harley davidson sportster,883,harley 883,harley davidson 883,harley-davidson 883,ama,american motorcycle association,speedvision,american thunder,high octane,american iron,motorcycle tour & cruiser,cyril huze,cyril huze motorcycles,bikers choice,custom chrome,chrome specialties,chrome specialties inc,drag specialties,performance machine,kuryakyn,sampson,paul yaffe originals,paul yaffe,cycle shack,buell,buell motorcycles,victory,victory motorcycles,ultra,ultra motorcycles,thunder motorcycles,white brothers,screamin' eagle,screamin' eagle parts,thunder cycle,surgical steeds,pro-one,pro-one motorcycles,pure steel,pure steel motorcycles,confederate motorcycles,exile,exile cycles,california customs,california custom motorcycles,bourget's bike works,bourget's motorcycles,boar motor company,american iron horse,v twin,j&p cycles,barnetts harley davidson,barnetts harley-davidson,motorcycle tires,harley tires,harley davidson tires,firebolt,buell firebolt,hayabusa,hayabusa motorcycles,cycle world,bsa,bsa motorcycles,norton,norton motorcycles,ktm,ktm motorcycles,motorcycle events,bike nights,bikenights,motorcycle bikenights,pastrana,travis pastrana,biketoberfest,loughlin,loughlin river run,americade,rainsuits,rain suits,classic,h-d,shadow,honda shadow,shadow motorcycle,blue ridge,blue ridge parkway,blue ridge touring,blue ridge tours,blue ridge mountains,gilleys pub,gilleys pub 44,cabbage patch,broken spoke,broken spoke saloon,excelsior,excelsior-henderson,escelsior motorcycles,ride to the wall,helmet laws,swingarm,motorcycle runs,s&s cycle,toy run,toy runs,abate,hells angels,gwrra,goldwing roadriders,association,goldwing road riders association,southern cruisers,southern cruisers motorcycle club,blue knights,blue knights motorcycle club,las vegas bike week,hollister races,dyna,dyna lowrider,dyna super glide,harley dyna super glide,harley dyna lowrider,harley dyna,harley davidson dyna,harley davidson,dyna super glide,harley davidson dyna lowrider,buell lightning,buell cyclone,american iron magazine,hot bike,hot bike magazine,v twin magazine,rolling thunder,walnecks,shovelhead,panhead,knucklehead,evo,evolution,revolution,harley shovelhead,harley panhead,harley knucklehead,harley evo,harley evolution,weanie bite,peter fonda,willie g,willie g davidson,lorenzo lamas,shaquille o'neal,jay leno,shaq,evil knievel,robbie knievel,bubba blackwell,hulk hogan,hulkster,born to ride,btr,full throttle,full throttle magazine,poker run,poker runs,handlebar,ron simms,ron simms motorcycles,helmets,motorcycle helmets,bubbs,bubbs pipes,bubbs motorcycle pipes,titan,titan motorcycles,titan motorcycle,indian chief,indian scout,hawk,honda hawk,rebel,honda rebel,tow truck,flat bed,millers,millers motorcycle parts,millers daytona,millers daytona beach">

<?php include 'site/inc/www2-css.php'; ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $linkedURL; ?>/site/quote.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>
<?php include 'site/inc/www2-header-insurance.php'; ?>
    <div id="body"> 
      <div id="quote">
        <img src="<?php echo $linkedURL; ?>/images/motorcycle-insurance-quote.jpg" alt="free motorcycle insurance quote" />
          <div class="errors">
<?php
//Check Required Information
if (!empty($_POST)) {
 echo "         <ul>\n";
    if(empty($d1_fname))    {echo "         <li>First Name Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_lname))    {echo "         <li>Last Name Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_add))      {echo "         <li>Address Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_city))     {echo "         <li>City Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if($d1_state=="STATE")  {echo "         <li>State Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_zip))      {echo "         <li>Zip Code Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_county))   {echo "         <li>County Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_email))    {echo "         <li>E-Mail Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_phone1) || empty($d1_phone2) ||empty($d1_phone3))
                            {echo "         <li>Phone Number Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}
    if(empty($d1_contact))  {echo "         <li>Preferred Contact Required</li>\n";}else{$complete = $complete + 1;}

    ////////
    // Check reCAPTCHA and hook into pre existing bad system.
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($recaptcha_privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    // this is where the hook into the bad system comes into play
    if(!$resp->is_valid) { echo "           <li>The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly.</li>\n"; } else { $complete += 1; }
    ////////

    if($complete==11){
    date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    $added = $updated = date('YmdHis');
    $d1_phone = $d1_phone1.'-'.$d1_phone2.'-'.$d1_phone3;
    // Connect
    include 'site/db/MCMonsterNetwork-db.php';
    $link = mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass");

    $select = mysql_select_db("$db_name", $link);

    if(!is_resource($link)) {

        echo "Failed to connect to the server";

    } elseif(!$select) {

        echo "Failed to select database";

    }else{
        // Make a safe query
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO quotes 
                        (d1_contact, d1_fname, d1_mname, d1_lname, d1_sname, d1_add, d1_city, d1_state, d1_zip, d1_county, d1_email, d1_phone, added, updated) 
                VALUES  ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_contact),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_fname),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_mname),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_lname),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_sname),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_add),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_city),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_state),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_zip),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_county),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_email),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($d1_phone),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($added),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($updated)
                    );

        mysql_query($query, $link);
        echo mysql_error();

    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_insert_id();
    $_SESSION['veh'] = 1;

$message =" 
        Name: 
        $d1_fname $d1_lname

        Email:
        $d1_email

        Address:        
        $d1_add
        $d1_city, $d1_state $d1_zip

        Phone:
        $d1_phone
";

    //mail( "motorcycleriders@msn.com", "Motorcycle Insurance Quote - $d1_fname $d1_lname", $message, "From: $d1_email" ); 
    smtpmail( "motorcycleriders@msn.com", "Motorcycle Insurance Quote - $d1_fname $d1_lname", $message, "From: MyMRA.com <no-reply@mymra.com>\r\nReply-To: $d1_email\r\n" ); 


    echo '
    <script language=javascript>
    setTimeout("location.href=\''.$secureURL.'/quote/Vehicles.php\'", 0000);
    </script>

    <center><b>If You are not redirected in 5 seconds <a href="'.$secureURL.'/quote/Vehicles.php">click here</a>.</b></center>  
    ';
  } 
 }
}
?>
          </div>
        <div id="quotebar">
        <ul>
            <li class="current">Information</li>
            <li>Vehicles</li>
            <li>Drivers</li>
            <li>Incidents</li>
            <li>Additional Info</li>
            <li>Complete</li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--close quotebar-->
        <div id="quotebox">
        <form action="<?php echo $secureURL; ?>/Motorcycle_Insurance_Quote.php" method="POST">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
          <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_fname" size="15" type="text" <?php if(!empty($d1_fname)){echo 'value="'.$d1_fname.'" ';} ?> /></td>
            <td>Middle Initial</td>
            <td><input name="d1_mname" size="1" type="text" <?php if(!empty($d1_mname)){echo 'value="'.$d1_mname.'" ';} ?> /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_lname" size="20" type="text" <?php if(!empty($d1_lname)){echo 'value="'.$d1_lname.'" ';} ?> /></td>
            <td>Suffix</td>
            <td>
            <select name="d1_sname">
              <option></option>
              <option value="Jr"<?php if($d1_sname=="Jr"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Jr</option>
              <option value="Sr"<?php if($d1_sname=="Sr"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Sr</option>
              <option value="I"<?php if($d1_sname=="I"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>I</option>
              <option value="II"<?php if($d1_sname=="II"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>II</option>
              <option value="III"<?php if($d1_sname=="III"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>III</option>
            </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Street Address</td>
            <td><input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_add" size="20" type="text" <?php if(!empty($d1_add)){echo 'value="'.$d1_add.'" ';} ?>/></td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td><input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_city" size="20" type="text" <?php if(!empty($d1_city)){echo 'value="'.$d1_city.'" ';} ?>/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>State</td>
            <td>
            <select style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_state">
              <option value="STATE"<?php if($d1_state=="STATE"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>-- Select --</option>
              <option value="AL"<?php if($d1_state=="AL"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Alabama</option>
              <option value="AZ"<?php if($d1_state=="AZ"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Arizona</option>
              <option value="AR"<?php if($d1_state=="AR"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Arkansas</option>
              <option value="CO"<?php if($d1_state=="CO"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Colorado</option>
              <option value="DE"<?php if($d1_state=="DE"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Delaware</option>
              <option value="FL"<?php if($d1_state=="FL"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Florida</option>
              <option value="GA"<?php if($d1_state=="GA"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Georgia</option>
              <option value="IL"<?php if($d1_state=="IL"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Illinois</option>
              <option value="IN"<?php if($d1_state=="IN"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Indiana</option>
              <option value="IA"<?php if($d1_state=="IA"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Iowa</option>
              <option value="KS"<?php if($d1_state=="KS"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Kansas</option>
              <option value="KY"<?php if($d1_state=="KY"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Kentucky</option>
              <option value="LA"<?php if($d1_state=="LA"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Louisiana</option>
              <option value="ME"<?php if($d1_state=="ME"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Maine</option>
              <option value="MI"<?php if($d1_state=="MI"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Michigan</option>
              <option value="MO"<?php if($d1_state=="MO"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Missouri</option>
              <option value="NE"<?php if($d1_state=="NE"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Nebraska</option>
              <option value="NV"<?php if($d1_state=="NV"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Nevada</option>
              <option value="NJ"<?php if($d1_state=="NJ"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>New Jersey</option>
              <option value="NY"<?php if($d1_state=="NY"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>New York</option>
              <option value="NC"<?php if($d1_state=="NC"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>North Carolina</option>
              <option value="ND"<?php if($d1_state=="ND"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>North Dakota</option>
              <option value="OH"<?php if($d1_state=="OH"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Ohio</option>
              <option value="OK"<?php if($d1_state=="OK"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Oklahoma</option>
              <option value="OR"<?php if($d1_state=="OR"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Oregon</option>
              <option value="PA"<?php if($d1_state=="PA"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Pennsylvania</option>
              <option value="RI"<?php if($d1_state=="RI"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Rhode Island</option>
              <option value="SC"<?php if($d1_state=="SC"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>South Carolina</option>
              <option value="SD"<?php if($d1_state=="SD"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>South Dakota</option>
              <option value="TN"<?php if($d1_state=="TN"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Tennessee</option>
              <option value="TX"<?php if($d1_state=="TX"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Texas</option>
              <option value="UT"<?php if($d1_state=="UT"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Utah</option>
              <option value="VA"<?php if($d1_state=="VA"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Virginia</option>
              <option value="WV"<?php if($d1_state=="WV"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>West Virginia</option>
              <option value="WI"<?php if($d1_state=="WI"){echo  ' selected="selected"';} ?>>Wisconsin</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td>Zip</td>
            <td><input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_zip" size="5" type="text" <?php if(!empty($d1_zip)){echo 'value="'.$d1_zip.'" ';} ?>/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>County</td>
            <td><input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_county" size="20" type="text" <?php if(!empty($d1_county)){echo 'value="'.$d1_county.'" ';} ?>/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>E-Mail Address</td>
            <td><input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_email" size="20" type="text" <?php if(!empty($d1_email)){echo 'value="'.$d1_email.'" ';} ?>/></td>
            <td>Home Phone</td>
            <td>
            (<input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_phone1" size="3" type="text" maxlength="3" <?php if(!empty($d1_phone1)){echo 'value="'.$d1_phone1.'" ';} ?>/>) 
            <input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_phone2" size="3" type="text" maxlength="3" <?php if(!empty($d1_phone2)){echo 'value="'.$d1_phone2.'" ';} ?>/>-
            <input style="background-color: #FEFEB6;" name="d1_phone3" size="4" type="text" maxlength="4" <?php if(!empty($d1_phone3)){echo 'value="'.$d1_phone3.'" ';} ?>/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Preferred Contact</td>
            <td colspan="3">
              <input name="d1_contact" value="1" type="radio" <?php if($d1_contact=="1"){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?>>E-Mail
              <input name="d1_contact" value="2" type="radio" <?php if($d1_contact=="2"){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?>>Phone
              <input name="d1_contact" value="3" type="radio" <?php if($d1_contact=="3"){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?>>USPS Mail
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />

        <h3>Call (866) 333-1829 for Fast Personal Service!</h3>
        <hr />

        <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><p>We appreciate you taking the time to submit your quote information. The MRA is an agency with several different A rated companies. We will shop the market for you to find the best rate. All the questions asked pertain to the many discounts our insurance companies offer. Should you have any questions about getting an insurance quote or would feel more comfortable talking to an agent please contact our office at <b>(866) 333-1829</b> 9:00am - 6:00pm EST Monday thru Friday.</p></td>
            <td><?php echo $siteSeal; ?></td>
        </tr>
        </table>        

        <hr />
        <p>We currently insure in the following states: Alabama, Arizona, Arkansas, Colorado, Delaware, Florida, Georgia, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana, Maine, Michigan, Missouri, Nebraska, Nevada, New Jersey, New York, North Carolina, North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Virginia, West Virginia and Wisconsin.</p>
        <hr />
        <p>If you have more than 2 drivers and/or 2 vehicles and would like to get a quote with, please call our Office Toll-Free at <b>(866) 333-1829</b>.</p>
        <hr />
    <center><?php echo recaptcha_get_html($recaptcha_publickey, null, true); ?></center>
        <hr />
        <p class="center"><input name="submit" value="Continue" src="<?php echo $linkedURL; ?>/images/continue-motorcycle-quote.jpg" type="submit"></p>
        </form>
        </div><!--close quotebox-->
      </div><!--close quote-->

<?php include 'site/inc/www2-footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is $d1_add actually initialized? i mean, do you set a value? because if you do it's not in the code you posted

Comment: Please post **all** your code.

Comment: you can do this by array and count item in array

Comment: Alright, posted. I'm willing to work with you all, I've been looking at this for days and I can't figure it out. Also can you further explain on your comment NullPonyPointer?

Comment: try taking this out `<?php if(!empty($d1_add)){echo 'value="'.$d1_add.'" ';} ?>` and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
        } else {
                $d1_fname           = $_POST['d1_fname'];
                $d1_lname           = $_POST['d1_lname'];
                $d1_mname           = $_POST['d1_mname'];
                $d1_sname           = $_POST['d1_sname'];
                $d1_city            = $_POST['d1_city'];
                $d1_state           = $_POST['d1_state'];
                $d1_zip             = $_POST['d1_zip'];
                $d1_county          = $_POST['d1_county'];
                $d1_phone1          = $_POST['d1_phone1'];
                $d1_phone2          = $_POST['d1_phone2'];
                $d1_phone3          = $_POST['d1_phone3'];
                $d1_email           = $_POST['d1_email'];
                $d1_contact         = $_POST['d1_contact'];
        }
```

To

```
        } else {
                $d1_add             = $_POST['d1_add'];
                $d1_fname           = $_POST['d1_fname'];
                $d1_lname           = $_POST['d1_lname'];
                $d1_mname           = $_POST['d1_mname'];
                $d1_sname           = $_POST['d1_sname'];
                $d1_city            = $_POST['d1_city'];
                $d1_state           = $_POST['d1_state'];
                $d1_zip             = $_POST['d1_zip'];
                $d1_county          = $_POST['d1_county'];
                $d1_phone1          = $_POST['d1_phone1'];
                $d1_phone2          = $_POST['d1_phone2'];
                $d1_phone3          = $_POST['d1_phone3'];
                $d1_email           = $_POST['d1_email'];
                $d1_contact         = $_POST['d1_contact'];
        }
```

On your last `else` statement. The problem is that the value is not being given a value, so it's going to return empty every time you POST

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't rep+ but anyone who can please do. Something so simple, yet I still missed it. Again thank you!

Comment: @Sriahciboon That's fine - but please mark the answer as accepted by checking the arrow on the left of the answer in order to mark the question as closed. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, I KNEW that it was $d1_add the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed below line at your last `else`

```
$d1_add             = $_POST['d1_add'];
```